# Swapping Two GameObjects on Keypress

Tags: boolean, transform, swap, gameobject

When I press Space, the player and the dummy are supposed to swap places. This doesn't just happen once, it needs to happen everytime I press the Space bar so they can swap back and forth. However, sometimes it works and sometimes it doesn't. When it doesn't work, the dummy teleports to the player and then the player teleports inside of the dummy (as that is where its last position is). This just kind of pushes the player about.
Here is the code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerSwap : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject player;
    public GameObject dummy;
    public GameObject cameraAnchor;

    public Transform playerLastPos;
    public Transform dummyLastPos;

    public bool haveSwapped;
    public bool canSwap;

    public float swapRadius;
    public LayerMask dummyInRadius;

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        canSwap = Physics.CheckSphere(player.transform.position, swapRadius, dummyInRadius);

        SwapTransforms();

        if (canSwap)
        {
            if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
            {
                haveSwapped = !haveSwapped;
                Swapping();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.Log("Can't Swap");
        }
        cameraAnchor.transform.position = player.transform.position;
    }

    public void SwapTransforms()
    {
        if (haveSwapped)
        {
            dummyLastPos.position = player.transform.position;
            playerLastPos.position = dummy.transform.position;
        }
        else
        {
            dummyLastPos.position = dummy.transform.position;
            playerLastPos.position = player.transform.position;
        }
    }

    public void Swapping()
    {
        if (haveSwapped)
        {
            player.transform.position = dummyLastPos.position;
            dummy.transform.position = playerLastPos.position;
        }
        else
        {
            player.transform.position = playerLastPos.position;
            dummy.transform.position = dummyLastPos.position;
        }
    }

    public void OnDrawGizmos()
    {
        Gizmos.color = Color.white;
        Gizmos.DrawWireSphere(player.transform.position, swapRadius);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've solved it. After cleaning up most of the code and realsing I had to turn off movement and the character controller on the player (Link:[Unity Answers](https://answers.unity.com/questions/1614287/teleporting-character-issue-with-transformposition.html)), I came up with this:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerSwap : MonoBehaviour
{
    public ThirdPersonMovement playerMove;

    public GameObject player;
    public GameObject dummy;
    public GameObject cameraAnchor;

    public Transform playerLastPos;
    public Transform dummyLastPos;

    public bool canSwap;

    public float swapRadius;
    public LayerMask dummyInRadius;

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        canSwap = Physics.CheckSphere(player.transform.position, swapRadius, dummyInRadius);

        if (canSwap)
        {
            if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
            {
                playerMove.canMove = false;
                player.GetComponent<CharacterController>().enabled = false;

                SetTransforms();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.Log("Can't Swap");
        }
        cameraAnchor.transform.position = player.transform.position;
    }

    public void SetTransforms()
    {
        dummyLastPos.position = dummy.transform.position;
        playerLastPos.position = player.transform.position;
        Debug.Log("Set Transforms");

        Swapping();
    }

    public void Swapping()
    {
        player.transform.position = dummyLastPos.position;
        dummy.transform.position = playerLastPos.position;
        dummy.transform.rotation = player.transform.rotation;
        Debug.Log("Swap");

        playerMove.canMove = true;
        player.GetComponent<CharacterController>().enabled = true;
    }

    public void OnDrawGizmos()
    {
        Gizmos.color = Color.white;
        Gizmos.DrawWireSphere(player.transform.position, swapRadius);
    }
}
```